# Trying to fetch a guild, using the "get()" method, but client returns undefined, although I have passed in client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

It was working fine earlier, but now it's just being weird.

```
module.exports = {
    commands: 'test',
    callback: (message, args, client) => {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ID') // 'ID' is a replacement for the actual guild ID I'm using. 
        console.log(guild) // client returns undefined
    }
}
```

(dumbed down to exclude code that is not relevant.)

**It was working before, I changed nothing regarding fetching the guild. It's been the same for weeks now, somehow it just doesn't work.***

**UPDATE:** Found the issue, originally, `callback()` accepted three params, I edited it to include `text` (Everything after the command, e.g. `!test test` would only pick up `test` and not `!test`)
So, in reality, `client` has been `arguments.join()` all along.
I figured this out after logging client, something I should have done *before* I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your code to this.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "test",
    execute(message, args, client){
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ID') // 'ID' is a replacement for the actual guild ID I'm using. 
        console.log(guild) // client returns undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work - isn't how my command handler is set up.